# How to repeat a certain operation across lines of code?

Tags: vim

I need to repeat a certain operation across several lines of code spread through out the code base. For instance,

```
x = y;
```

needs to be replaced with

```
EQUATE(x,y);
```

However each instance needs to be assessed manually, because say this needs to be done only when `x` and `y` have been declared as `unit16_t`. So the functionality I seek is to be able to browse through various files of interest and anytime I come across a line where I feel the above operation needs to run, I should be able to just press a certain sequence of keys that would substitute the given line of code with the desired change. So say if I come across a line somewhere else that looks like below

```
struct_x.var_x = struct_y.var_y;
```

I should just be able to replace it with

```
EQUATE(struct_x.var_x, struct_y.var_y);
```

with a simple set of keystrokes.

Comment: Why not use a macro?

Comment: This is great, just figured out how to use macros - am new to vim. It gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I used a macro to do this :

1. Start recording the macro with `qa` : `q` to start recording and then save in register `a`.
2. Move to the beginning of the line : `^`
3. Enter insert mode (`i`) and type `EQUATE(`.
4. Then search and replace operation in command mode : `:.s/\ = \ /,/g` - search for `=` and replace it with `,` on this line.
5. Move to the end of line with `$`, enter insert mode again and close the bracket.
6. Stop recording the macro - `q`

That's it! Replay the macro with `@a` at every other place you want to use it.

Comment: You can combine `^i` to `I` and `$a` to `A`. You don't need to specify `.` - the current line is the default range in `:s`. You don't need to escape spaces either: `:s/ = /,/g` works fine.